# How to remove certain table row by button click

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-delete

I created a table with data from my database. And I added a trashcan button with it to delete a specific row. The only thing I'm not sure about is what to select with my delete function.

```
<?php
    $klantenn = $app->get_alleKlantenA();
    foreach($klantenn as $alleKlantenn){
echo "
    <tr>
    <td>".$alleKlantenn['id']. "</td>
    <td>".$alleKlantenn['voornaam']. " " .$alleKlantenn['achternaam']."</td>
    <td>".$alleKlantenn['emailadres']."</td>
    <form action='' method='post`enter code here`'>
    <td><button type='submit' name='removeKlant'><i class='fa fa-trash'></i></button></td>
";

    public function remove_klant(){
            $removeKlant = $this->database->query("REMOVE * FROM klant WHERE ????");
            $removeklantResult = $this->database->single();
            return $removeklantResult;
        }
?>
```

**Update**

The table:

[image: I want to remove all data from the person where I pressed the button]

**What I want:**

I want to remove all data from the person where I pressed the button

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!
It really depends on what you wanna delete in the database and how the tables are set-up. Could you provide example data of the table **klant** and could you explain what exactly you want to remove when pressing the button? The MySQL syntax for removing rows is `DELETE FROM table`

Comment: @MBijen I have added the database table structure from klant.

Comment: @MBijen Thx for the help. It works fine now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table seems to have an `id` column. That's what you probably want to use to identify the table row to delete.

Now you need to send that ID when requesting the row deletion, so you add a hidden field with the row's in the delete form (each row will have its own form with the row ID in a hidden field).

On server you then use that Id to limit the DELETE SQL query like

```
delete from klant where id = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use "DELETE FROM table_name
WHERE some_column = some_value";

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <button name="Remove" type="submit" onclick="return 
     table_raw()">HTML</button>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>


public function table_raw(){
$delete_data = "DELETE FROM TableName WHERE ID= your_fetch_id";
return $delete_data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the filled in ID from the form as the WHERE clause. The ID seems to be the unique key so using only the ID is sufficient. Example: (WHERE id = $data)